VFD offset tutorial
I am trying to understand VFD's (Variable Frequency Drives) concept of 'offset' What is this feature? When do I use it. What does it achieve.
I have searched Youtube: lots about VFD but can't find anything on 'offset'
Tried Allen Bradley Literature and Mitsubishi Literature.
Results are too general.
Please advise.

Please [edit] your question to give some context. Where did you read about 'offset'?

Also, please tell us what DO you know or understand about it so far, and what exactly is not clear to you. It's hard to believe you have no idea about it after reading at least a couple of texts. Maybe your level of knowledge and understanding of electrical technology is lacking, and it will help us fine-tune our answers if you let us know where you stand with it.
